# Bookmarklet that opens and modifies page

Tags: bookmarklet

How can I create a bookmarklet that opens a new page and modifies its content? I tried

```
javascript:document.location.href = 'http://example.com'; function createDiv() { var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];var _div = document.createElement('div');var _text = document.createTextNode('Creating Div Element');_div.appendChild(_text);_body.appendChild(_div);};createDiv();
```

but the code does not modify the page in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only run a bookmarklet on a page that is already opened. Once you change the location, the script you started on another page can no longer affect the new page.

**EDIT:** I just now discovered something amazing. In Chrome, if you use CTRL+click on the bookmarklet, it is possible to make a bookmarklet that works this way. AFAIK, this works only in Chrome and only if you use CTRL+click.

You must modify your code slightly for that to work:

```
javascript: window.location.href = 'http://example.com'; window.onload = function(){ function createDiv() { var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];var _div = document.createElement('div');var _text = document.createTextNode('Creating Div Element');_div.appendChild(_text);_body.appendChild(_div);};createDiv();}; void(0);
```